# How can we use the =IMPORTXML function in Google Sheets to get the data from a custom attribute or an attribute generated using Angular?

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

The site URL is as follows:https://fyers.in/margin-calculator/equity-margin/
I want to scrape the data from the symbol columns using Google Sheets.[image]

But, unfortunately, I am getting #N/A as a result, I am using the IMPORT XML function in Google Sheet as follows

=IMPORTXML(A1,B1)

A1= https://fyers.in/margin-calculator/equity-margin/
B1= //td[@data-title-text="Symbol"]

[image]

I believe the issue here is because the website is built it Angular it could be dynamically generating data or the Google Sheets XML does not support a custom attribute such as data-title-text.

Please let me know what I can do further, Thanks.

Comment: From the attributes on the site, it appears that the site is actually using the former AngularJS framework, not the Angular framework.

Comment: Yes, I am not that much aware of Angular or Angular JS, just searched one of the terms on Google and found that it has something to do with Angular.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using [`IMPORTHTML`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339?hl=en) instead? It's a better alternative to `IMPORTYML` in that you don't have to specify the query to search for - instead, you provide the index of the table on the site that you're querying for.

Comment: I tried IMPORTHTML, {{row.no}} {{row.exchange}} {{row.symbol}} {{row.imul}}x  this is the result I get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bit hard. Website uses dynamic rendering. Selenium is defintely required here. But we can try with GoogleSheets. First, and after locating data, I use 2 IMPORTXML and susbtring functions to overcome the cell-size limit. Next, I join the result with an ARRAYFORMULA+QUERY. Then, I SPLIT and TRANSPOSE. To finish I extract the symbols with STXT or REGEXEXTRACT.

[image: Flyers]

[Symbols.Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rZLiChNHp9Vyz9oQQzFon3aUvb5oWJYRjqlV_Uj9fWA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: This was on point solution thanks, now my next step is to extract the "imul" value

Comment: Sheet has been updated with 2 regex to rebuild the entire table. You can check the green headers.

Comment: Thank you so much for that :D